# unordered_multimap<string, string> to map<string, string> soft search, How to do such thing and how to preprocessed maps for faster search?

Tags: c++, search, boost, unordered

We have a `map<boost::shared_ptr<service>, rules> service_map` where rules is

```
struct rules
{
boost::unordered_multimap<string, string> set_of_rules_1;
boost::unordered_multimap<string, string> set_of_rules_2;
}
```

In my case of rules are pairs from of http request `headers` and `arguments`, for example in one such unordered_multimap we could find `Accept-Language : FR` and `Accept-Language : US`.

Each `boost::shared_ptr<service>` is some instance of class that inherits from `service class`.

I fill this map of servise <-> rules on fly with services and rules (from some shared libs and some text files with rules).

Now I am given instances of `data`

```
struct data
{
map<string, string> headers;
map<string, string> arguments;
}
```

For each given `data` object I need to find most relevant `service` from `service_map` and call its `service->inherited_method();`

By relevant here we mean one whose rules fit to given data mostly. For example if we have in rules  `Accept-Language : FR` and `Accept-Language : US` than if data contains pair `Accept-Language : fr-FR,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` we think it is relevant.

What would be best way to preprocess my service_map for faster soft search, and how to implement such search?

Comment: Is this only about Accept-Language, or will there be other dimensions you are trying to match on?  Less talk about the C++ details and more about the actual concepts and expected data variations would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tall order, and you'll have to develop some of the logic yourself. However, here's a skeleton solution:

1) Write a function that ranks rules according to their relevance for a given set of data:

```
int relevance(const rules & r, const data & d); // write this
```

2) For each piece of data, create a sorted ranking of the rules. For instance, you could keep a bunch of iterators around. Then find the service that matches the most relevant rule set.

```
typedef RuleCollection::const_iterator rit;

boost::shared_ptr<service> find_service(cosnt data & d, ...)
{
  std::multimap<int, rit> relevant_rules;

  for (rit it = rc.begin(), end = rc.end(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    // relevant_rules[relevance(*it, d)] = it; // sorry, that was nonsense
    relevant_rules.insert(std::make_pair(relevance(*it, d), it));
  }

  for (auto it = relevant_rules.rbegin(), rend = relevant_rules.rend(); it != rend; ++it)
  {
    for (auto st = service_map.begin(), end = service_map.end(); st != end; ++st)
    {
      if (*st->second == *it->second) return st->first;
    }
  }
  throw std::exception("Could not find suitable service.");
}
```

I'm supposing that all your rules are kept in `RuleCollection rc;`, some container of value type `rules`.

*Edit:* Fixed multimap element insertion -- multimap does not have a `[]` access operator for obvious reasons.